# Is there an OpenSource tool to convert from Clover to Cobertura xml format?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, cobertura, clover

I'm looking for a tool to convert from Clover to Cobertura xml format. Is there a good OpenSource tool to do this?

Comment: I'm looking for the reverse of this.  [This python project](https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml) may be able to help you get started, but it isn't the complete solution either of us is looking for.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as off-topic since it involves tools used for programming to generate coverage reports. Just because someone doesn't know the tools of stack doesn't mean they should close the question.

Answer (score 2):

See this: https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml

It converts the xml compatible to Cobertura

Comment: Does Clover output reports in an lcov format?